# How can I configure Google Play so that it doesn't update applications when I'm using the phone?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I'd like to configure Google Play so that it doesn't update applications when I'm using my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3) or tablet (Nexus 7).

Note that I still want to have the auto-update, but **only when I'm not using the phone.**

Comment: "Not using the phone" means when it is in sleep/locked? or when you are not running any apps?? Please be specific.. And also tell why you need this strange requirement..

Comment: As of now the play store only controls whether apps are auto updated on wifi or not. No inbuilt solution I believe

I am assuming your phone slows down when this happens, other than that I dont see why you should need this.

Comment: @Keshava The Nexus 7 gets really slow, Samsung Galaxy S3 to a lesser extent. Not using the phone = sleep/locked, or not running any apps, any way is good.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt AFAIK, `Disabling the auto-update, and manually updating all apps when you are not using phone` is only option available for now...

Answer (score 2):

You can use an app for automating tasks, like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm),  [AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage), etc.

[Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/44779/16853), for example, is a suggestion for a Tasker profile that enables auto update only when the device is plugged in for charging. You may be able to find an alternative trigger that better suits your needs, like screen off, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) to hibernate google pay store and services.(only if your phone is rooted.)