# How to create a profile with multiple context in Tasker?

Tags: tasker

Right now by default, Tasker runs my task when any of the context (aka. profile) are met.

I want to have the task only activate when *all* of the context are met:  location *and* time, et cetera.

How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add more contexts to existing profile by:

1. Tap the profile to display the context
2. Long-press the context
3. Select **Add +**
4. Choose the context you want to add

For example, if you want to have location & time as the contexts:

1. On *Profiles* tab, tap **+** icon and select the first context: **Location**.
2. Create or choose the location
3. Create or choose the task
4. On *Home* profile, long-press the location name until a pop-up appears; press **Add +**
5. Select the second context: **Time**
6. After configuring the time, press **Back** to finish it

---

In case you want to remove a context without deleting the profile:

1. Tap the profile to display the context
2. Long-press the context
3. Select **Delete**
4. Select **OK** to confirm

Warning: if there is only 1 context, deleting it will also delete the profile.

Comment: Is there any way to have more than four contexts?

Comment: @Shayan I believe that is a good question that should be posted as a new, stand-alone question :)