# Configure screen on/off: charging/time of day

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to configure my tablets such that if the device is plugged into a charger and it is between, say, 7 am and 10pm, then the screen doesn't turn off, otherwise, it will. Is this possible?

Edit ------

[image]

Comment: You can add multiples triggers. See [How to create a profile with multiple context in Tasker?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/120974) Trigger one would be Time from 07:00-22:00 and the the action would be Display Timeout to maximum. Add another trigger by long pressing the first trigger, select `+` and set the trigger to State -> Power -> Power. Done! This results in AND logic.

Comment: @Firelord I was writing up how to do that earlier this morning but, got caught up in stuff, now you managed to get ahead of me in supplying the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a profile with the criteria that needs to be meet for it to work. E.g Time and Power.

1. Create a Task
2. Choose Display -> Display timeout
3. set the timeout 59 Secs, 59 mins and 23 Hours or longer if you want

***This is were the instructions differ from the above user***

4. Go to your profiles tab
5. Create  a new profile
6. Chose the first Context/trigger as the time frame you desire, which is 7am to 10 pm
7. Chose the wanted task
8. Once the profile has been created click and hold on to the time setting context/trigger (The box within your profile that you created)
9. After that you get shown with a list of items, click add > State > Power and then chose the desired choice (I left it as any - this includes AC, USB and Wireless charging)
10. Click done. Now you have created a profile that activates only at a certin time while it is being supplied power

Hope I could help you get this working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily enough with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). You can create a task that:

- checks if the device is on charge (to do it you can either use the extended variable %myPOWER provided [here](http://tasker.wikidot.com/extendedvariables) or create your own global variable)
- checks for the time of the day
- sets the screen timeout to 'never'

Create a task with two actions.
The first one:

1. Choose Display ->  Display timeout
2. Set all sliders to the maximum, it means never power off the screen
3. Add this 'if' condition (tap the plus sign at the bottom of the page): %myPOWER = ac (use 'Math: Equals' to set the field in the middle)

For the second task, set minutes to your normal timeout time and add the condition: %myPOWER = none.

Now create a profile:

1. Choose 'Time' as the context for the profile
2. Set from 7:00 to 22:00
3. Enter the name of the task you created

Comment: Ok, i have Tasker. I clicked + to add action. Now what?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Should this be one task with 2 actions or 2 tasks?

Comment: One task with two actions will do.

Comment: Did that. Now how do I turn it on, so to speak? Do I have to create a profile?

Comment: Again edited the answer, sorry if it was unclear and not the most efficient way. Now it should be better

Comment: I have it all now, but it has no effect.I restarted the device in case that mattered. I've added a screenshot of the task to the question. Does it look correct?

Comment: Check my new edit of the answer.

Comment: I can't get this to work. In the system settings, I have the display set to 2 minutes and this is what happens. The task does not override this.