# Do not disturb/Priority mode until next alarm on Android 6.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, alarm, do-not-disturb

Android 5.1 introduced an option of enabling priority mode until the next alarm. I used that feature on a daily basis.

Now, with the redesign of the Do not disturb/Priority mode in Android 6.0, I can't seem to find that option. Further research suggests that this feature has been removed.

So first, am I missing something obvious and that option is still there?
And second, If this option was indeed removed, is there a more 'advanced' way of getting the priority mode to end after my next alarm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: this feature is back on Android 6.0.1**.

According to [Android Police - Android 6.0.1 Brings Back The "Until Next Alarm" Option For Do Not Disturb Mode](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/12/07/android-6-0-1-brings-back-the-until-next-alarm-option-for-do-not-disturb-mode/),

> With Android 6.0.1, the "until next alarm" feature makes its triumphant (or rather quiet, I suppose) return. Good to know!

---

> So first, am I missing something obvious and that option is still there?

Looks like it has been removed on Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Nexus 5 on the same Android version also only have 2 options: *Until you turn this off*, and *For x amount of time*.

> And second, If this option was indeed removed, is there a more 'advanced' way of getting the priority mode to end after my next alarm?

Automation apps like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (paid) may be able to replicate the same behavior as the one on Android 5.x Lollipop.

1. Create a profile for an alarm clock

   1. On the *Profiles* tab, tap the **+** button
   2. Select **Event - Date/Time - Alarm Clock**
   3. Press back to finish
2. Create a task to turn off Priority mode

   1. Select **New Task** on the pop-up (or from *Tasks* tab, tap **+** button)
   2. Input the task name (e.g. "Turn off DnD", optional), then tap the checkmark
   3. Tap **+**, select **Audio - Do Not Disturb**
   4. For **Mode**, select **All** (this means "allows all interruption", which is the same as turning off Priority mode)

   - If this is the first time using Do Not Disturb, Tasker will prompt a dialog box to turn on **Notification Access**. Select **Yes**, tap **Tasker** to enable it, and select **Allow**.

Basically, this will make *all alarms turn off the Priority mode*. To refine the time, (e.g. for a specific alarm at 6 AM on weekdays), add other contexts (e.g. **Time** and **Date**) by following [How to create a profile with multiple context in Tasker?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120968/how-to-create-a-profile-with-multiple-context-in-tasker/120974#120974)