# How to Allow Caller Who Can Call You During "Alarms Only"?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, alarm

I am using Android 6.0. 
I would like to allow my mother call me also when the mode "Alarms only" is active. I have her in Starred contacts i.e. priority list. She calls me to double verify that I wake up in some mornings.

I would like the caller can vibrate your phone even in the Alarms only mode.

How can you setup a caller who can call and disturb you by vibration during the mode *Alarms only*?

Comment: Why not use Priority only mode? You can setup favorite contacts in it.

Comment: @Firelord It is not enough. I have three contacts there. I want only one caller who can contact me during *Alarms only*.

Comment: @Firelord Thank you for the clarification! I clarified the body by describing that the one caller can disturb you also in the Alarms only mode by causing a vibration of the phone, which is not possible normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) in this case. Although I tried so, I still couldn't come up with a non-root method.

Follow these instructions:

- Profile: Event → Phone → Phone Ringing:

  - Caller: A single Contact → choose your contact
  - Priority: Highest

  You can add multiple contacts there. It is not relevant here whether your contact is a starred contact or is allowed in Priority mode's list.
- Task: (Actions):

  - Code → Run Shell:

    - Command: `settings get global zen_mode`
    - tick Use Root
    - Store Output In: `%ZenMode`
  - Task → If → Condition:

    - `%ZenMod` `eq` `2`
    - `Or`
    - `%ZenMode` `eq` `3`
  - Alert → Vibrate → Time: 1000
  - Task → Wait → Seconds: 2
  - Task → Goto:

    - Type: Action Number
    - Number: 3

  The first action stores the status of *Do Not Disturb* mode. The second action checks whether the device is currently in *Alarms only* or *Total Silence* mode. (Remove `%ZenMod` `eq` `2` if you don't want to be disturbed during *Total Silence* mode). If yes, then when the call from that particular contact comes in, the device will vibrate.  You can customize the settings for Vibrate and Wait action. Their job is to vibrate the device then wait for few seconds. The use of Goto causes the task to follow the same vibrate and wait cycle for infinite times.
- Profile: You need to setup two contexts. See [How to create a profile with multiple context in Tasker?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/120968/96277) for related help.

  - Event → Phone → Phone Idle → Priority: Highest
  - State → Tasker → Task Running → Name: select the task you assigned to first profile - the same task meant to vibrate the device
- Task: (Actions): Task → Stop → Task: select the task meant to vibrate the device

This profile would make sure that the vibration stops only when either the incoming call is dismissed by yourself or ends up as a missed call simply because the caller  dismissed the call from their end or you didn't pick up the call resulting in timeout.

- Profile:

  - Event → Phone → Phone Offhook → Priority: Highest
  - State → Tasker → Task Running → Name: select the task you assigned to first profile - the same task meant to vibrate the device
- Task: (Actions): Task → Stop → Task: select the task meant to vibrate the device

This profile makes sure that the vibration stops once the call is picked up by you.

Try it. It worked on my unofficial CM13.