# Using Tasker to know if I'm at work for more than a minute

Tags: tasker

I use Tasker's **Wifi Near** option to activate some tasks in my phone when I arrive at my workplace. My problem is that sometimes I pass by my workplace, with no intention of entering, and the tasks get activated.

Is there a way to make Tasker activate the tasks **IF** I've been near my workplace's wifi spots for more than a minute?

Comment: Have you tried with [multiple contexts](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120968/how-to-create-a-profile-with-multiple-context-in-tasker/120974#120974)? A location context may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Tasker › Wait* in the task. When your *WiFi near* fired, just have it waiting for e.g. 5min, then exit if no longer WiFi near, otherwise continue with your task.

You could also bring variables into play, e.g. setting `%STAYATWORK` to `1` if the WiFi is still in reach after the wait, and have your other tasks using that as context. In this case, don't forget to reset `%STAYATWORK` to `0` (or unset it) if the WiFi is no longer in reach :)

Comment: How would I know that Wifi Near is still active after the waiting time?

Comment: There's e.g. the `%WIFII` variable you can check, [see user-guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html).