# Turn screen off if tilted a certain way

Tags: screen

Phones in bed mean poor sleeping habits.

How would one go about turning the screen off, or fuzzing the screen (probably more practical, less subject to temporary tilt), if the device is tilted in certain ways?

For example,

- Device is vertically upside down.
- Device is locked in Portrait mode and horizontal.
- Screen is facing the center of the Earth.

Answers using apps will be accepted, but, out of interest in the theory, I will also accept answers that outline an app to do such a thing. I know that newer Android versions have screen filters and tilt sensors.

Comment: What do you mean by fuzzing the screen?

Comment: @Firelord: I imagine it would be difficult to distract yourself from sleep if the screen was blurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Device is vertically upside down.
> - Device is locked in Portrait mode and horizontal.
> - Screen is facing the center of the Earth.

I suggest you try [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) ([user guide](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/index.html)) as well as [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) ([free trial](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html); [user guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/)). Both of them offer the features you're seeking. A peek:

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Before I leave you here to tinker with those options, here is some information to ease the tinkering:

In Automate app:

- [Device Orientation](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/device_orientation.html) block can be found under Sensors.
- [Device lock](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/device_lock.html) can be found under Interface. Practical usage requires setting Automate as device administrator.

*Tip*: It is easy in Automate to trigger an action on a prerecorded [motion gesture](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/motion_gesture.html)

In Tasker app:

- Orientation trigger can be found under State → Sensor.
- Display Orientation trigger can be found under State → Display.
- System Lock action can be found under Display.

*Tip*: In Tasker you can setup [multiple contexts](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120974/96277).