# How to launch an app immediately after another app is closed using Tasker

Tags: applications, tasker

I need help creating a *Tasker* profile that will open *Aldiko Sync*  **ONLY** after I have ended the main Aldiko Premium app.

So with this profile, Aldiko Sync automatically launches and does its thing immediately after I close Aldiko Premium reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup an [exit task](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide_summary.html#activity_main.html). An exit task is assigned from the Profiles tab. Expand the entry of your profile, long-press the assigned task there and choose Add Exit Task.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

#### Instructions:

- Profile: Application → *your app* (Aldiko Premium in this case)
- Task: (Actions): do anything you want
- Exit task: (Actions): App → *your another app* (Aldiko Sync in this case)

**Note**: It is not mandatory to have an enter task in order to assign an exit task to a profile.

If you don't want an enter task i.e. don't want a task to be run when the profile is triggered, you can choose to create a task (supposed to be used as an exit task) under Tasks tab, assign it as an enter task to a profile and make it an exit task using Move to Exit (see screenshot).