# Execute task if tasker profile has been active for some time

Tags: tasker, automation

How can I execute a tasker task only after a certain condition has been true for a certain time?

Normally a profile executes its task as soon as all conditions are met. I want to delay this activation, until the conditions have stayed true for some time.

E.g.

- do something after the screen has been continuously off or on for 10 minutes
- do something after wifi xy has not been near for 10 minutes
- do something after cell towers x,y,z have not been near for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A mix of Wait, [Variable Search](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html) and If-Else should suffice here.

Tasker [maintains](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html) a variable named Profiles Active, denoted by `%PACTIVE`.

> **Profiles Active** <sub>(dynamic)</sub>
>   %PACTIVE
>   A comma-separated list of the currently active, named profiles in activation order. **Duplicate names will appear on the list only once**. The list always starts and ends with a comma to make matching easier, if it's not empty.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

You can use Wait action to wait for N amount of time and then check whether your profile is active or not. If not active, exit out of the task, else, continue.

You may begin your task with these actions:

1. Task → Wait → configure it
2. Variables → Variable Set:

   - Name: `%ActiveProfiles`
   - To: `%PACTIVE`
3. Variables → Variable Search Replace:

   - Variable: `%ActiveProfiles`
   - Search: `,PROFILE_NAME,`
   - tick Ignore Case
   - Store Matches In: `%CurrentProfile`

   Replace `PROFILE_NAME` with the name of your profile. **A profile's name must be setup manually.**
4. Task → If: `%CurrentProfile1` `Isn't Set`
5. Task → Stop

   Alternatively, put any action that notifies you that the profile deactivated in the mean time.
6. Task → Else
7. Setup the actions you want be executed if the profile remains active after N amount of time.

Comment: This approach has issues. The first issue is that I'm not making any checks on the fact that for the amount of time I'm waiting, the profile may have deactivated and activated multiple times. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: For the obvious issue here: setup an [Exit Task](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/135199/96277) and stop the Enter Task from it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

What I do with success :

**myprofile 1 →**

*what I want for activation*

⇒

**Task 1 Delay →**

1. Wait *x time to comfirm activation*
2. Set %variable_Active = 1
3. Wait 1 second
4. Set %variable_Active = 0

=== **AND** ===

**myprofileActivate →**

1. %variable_Active == 1
2. %myprofile is active

⇒

**Task 1 Actions →**

*what I want to see done*

Comment: Welcome on the Android SE! I see your answer is a little bit cryptic, could you please explain for the future readers, exactly what are you doing?