# How to lock camera and volume control when phone is locked

Tags: lock-screens

When my phone is locked, the camera and volume controls still work which I find strange.

How can I lock these down also, I don't want these controls to be pressed when in my pocket by mistake.

Comment: Which Android version and device are you using? Is the Android rooted? If yes, then [Xposed Additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) could help, provided that your ROM is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

My device doesn't have a separate camera key, so I was able to test my solutions only with volume up and down keys. [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (full [7 day trial](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html); [userguide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/)) is what you can try. You would either have to buy or enable full trial of former since the solution featuring AutoInput would not work.

**Important:** Launch AutoInput and enable its accessibility service.

For Tasker:

1. Profile: State → Display → Display State → Is: Off
2. Task: (Action):

   - Plugin → AutoInput → Modes

     - Configuration:

       - Key Suppress: Enable
       - Keys: tick the entries *viz.* Volume Up, Volume Down and Camera
     - Timeout: None
3. [Exit task](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/135199/96277): (Action):

   - Plugin → AutoInput → Modes

     - Configuration:

       - Key Suppress: Disable
       - Keys: tick the entries *viz.* Volume Up, Volume Down and Camera
     - Timeout: None

That did the job in stock Android 6.0.1 in Nexus 6, at least for volume rockers.

---

On a rooted Android, you can try [Xposed Additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) app. It requires a compatible Xposed Framework<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>.

Instructions:

1. Launch **Xposed Additions** → tap **Buttons**
2. Tap **Add new key** and when the dialog appears press your hardware key once to register it
3. Tap the newly created entry for the button you pressed earlier
4. Tap **Add new Condition** → **Screen Off**
5. Tap the newly created Screen Off entry → tick Click under Single Actions

Follow the said instructions for the rest of your relevant hardware keys.

**Note:** If Ambient Display is enabled, then during the moments when the display lightens up briefly, pressing any of the relevant keys would result in their actual intended effect and not the one the two solutions aim for.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>  <sub>Xposed Framework: [Android 4.x](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), [Android 5.x and 6.x](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)</sub>