# Automatic app updating interrupts video

Tags: applications, updates, video

I have a Google Nexus 6P. Irritatingly enough, when apps are finished updating, whatever video I'm watching in whatever app is paused. Every time. And when you can't schedule app updates for when you're asleep or just not using your phone, this becomes quite annoying even though it sounds like a trivial issue. Usually there are about six updates every day, and they all are seemingly updated around about the same time at which I go to bed and watch a TV-series or some YouTube videos.

Frequently having to unpause the video is not only immensely frustrating, but also ruining the flow and action of the story of what I'm watching.

So is there a way to schedule app updates, or in some other way resolve this issue?

Comment: Raw concept (untested): Use [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tasker) and *Greenify*. Profile something like "When app X is running › Greenify Playstore". When greenified, it won't do updates.

Comment: In case the device is rooted and auto update of apps is set to "over Wi-Fi only", you can try my answer: [How to allow auto-update of apps in Play Store only when plugged in?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/137376) The context can be whatever you want instead of "plugged in" as noted there.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my Nexus 6P. Everything I see online says "You internet is too slow," but I am on campus and my DL speed is 147 Mbps, so it's not that. Just curious: are you using stock ROM or have you flashed a custom ROM?

Comment: I have a download speed of 260 Mbps, so nor for me is that the answer. To answer your question, I don't know what any of those are so I guess stock ROM.

Comment: +1 as I am also experiencing this issue. It occurs every time that an app has been downloaded and finishes installing the update. It somewhat reminds me of music players turning the volume down by half briefly whenever you get a notification, but instead of a minor interruption it causes playback to cease completely and requiring manual resuming.

Comment: Additional reports found: http://forums.androidcentral.com/nexus-6p/670952-youtube-videos-pause-during-app-updates.html https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/4a0vl4/how_to_prevent_google_play_updates_to_interrupt/  https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/play/oaPE7dQD_uo

Comment: Almost a year later and I still experience this :( Very few other people seem to so I don't know if it will ever be resolved.