# How to restart a system app from the command line?

Tags: command-line, system-apps

After deploying a new APK for a system app, is there a way to restart the app process without rebooting the device?

Non-system apps are managed with the Activity Manager through the `am` command. There are options like `start`, `restart`, `force-stop`, as well as commands against services, like `startservice` or `stopservice`.

I have mainly read and tried around the Activity Manager, and I am missing something. Right now, I just rely on the time-consuming brutal `reboot` command. Posts on installing system apps also use `reboot` only, as far as I found.

Great and timely feedback mention the very commands I tried, but when they work, they are in "force" mode. I did not check the source code, but it usually means something akin to `kill -s SIGKILL`, and I wonder whether that is really necessary to go that far.

---

Some sample outputs (thanks everyone for comments!):

(note, I have indented the command output for readability)

#### Restarting with `restart`

```
$:/ # am start com.android.email
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=com.android.email }
$:/ # ps | grep email
    u0_a30    1436  117   705400 32128 ffffffff 4006b954 S com.android.email
$:/ # am restart com.android.email
    Restart the system...
    android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.restart(ActivityManagerNative.java:4647)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runRestart(Am.java:1410)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:308)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:78)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
$:/ # ps | grep email
$:/ # #=> Process was killed anyway
$:/ # am start com.android.email #=> Works again, but the previous error...
```

#### Restarting with `force-stop`

```
$:/ # am start com.android.email
$:/ # ps | grep email
    u0_a30    2680  1506  706404 31668 ffffffff 40059954 S com.android.email
$:/ # am force-stop com.android.email
$:/ # ps | grep email
$:/ # #=> Process killed
$:/ # am start com.android.email #=> Works again, but it was *forced* kill!
```

---

Some context and idiosyncrasies: My particular case is a custom system app (in `/system/priv-app`) that exposes a service, no activity. I am used to rely on `am startservice` and `am stopservice` to manage non-system processes. It does not work properly for system apps (read: "I don't know how to do it" :-) ). All this is on Android 4.4.2, API level 19.

Comment: Not really an answer, but faster than a complete reboot it should be to do a soft reboot (i.e. kill the system server). Though I don't know how to do that from the command line (I've normally used the boot menu for that ;) my guess is you simply use the `kill` command on its process once you've identified that (`ps | grep system_server` should help you find its PID): `kill $(ps | grep system_server | awk '{print $2}')`. That said: if you can identify the PID of that app, it should work the same way (but might have side effects).

Comment: @Izzy Isn't it something like `busybox killall system_server`. I used that command before in an app I made.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab As I wrote, I didn't try that myself – so you could be right. Still, consider `busybox` is not a given on all devices – while `kill` usually is (IMHO; with no `busybox` it often points to `toolbox` or the like), as are `ps` and `grep`. Admittedly, `awk` again might depend on `busybox`, so one might have to do the kill manually in two steps then.

Comment: Doesn't the above just restart userland, similar to `am restart`?  ([Related](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43706/1465).)  In any case: Eric, could you clarify what the problem is using `am start`?  It works fine on my device for system apps.

Comment: Thank you all. @Matthew Read, the problem is to have a custom system app restart completely. `am restart` does not work for me, but I may be using it wrong. I cite it, although I do not believe that is right. @all, it would be great to restart without external tooling, if possible. I guess that should be possible properly on such a fully-fledged OS !

Comment: Yeah I didn't expected `am restart` to work, but `am force-stop` & `am start` should.  What happens when you try it?

Comment: @EricPlaton : I can give my assurance that a system app can be force-stopped completely  and one of its component can be started from scratch again. My answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/137376/96277) can show you that (hint: com.android.vending is a system app). // *Can you precisely tell us what in that app are you trying to restart*? `am start -S COMPONENT` would force-stop the app and then start your app's component. `am force-stop PACKAGE` and then `am start` or `am startservice` can help you as well.

Comment: Thank you all, again! I have updated the question to address most of your feedback. I see that there are solutions, but don't you feel weird that you have to *force* stop a process to restart? That's one of the motivation for the question, and I should clarify it.

Comment: I'll have to take a peek around the source code and see whether the Android system itself does a `kill` when updating an app.